# Recursive follow files in bash

Tags: bash, file, recursion

I have files which contain file names pointing to other files. These files contain further file names pointing further files and so on. I need a bash script which follows each files recursively and logs into file every touched file during the run.

```
file1:
   file2
   file3

file2:
   file4

file3:
   file5
```

file4 and file5 are empty.
Result:

```
file1
file2
file4
file3
file5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

```
function scan() {
  echo $1
  local f
  while read f ; do
    scan $f
  done < $1
}
```

Use:

```
scan file1 > log
```

Update: accepted Dennis Williamson comment and replaced `cat $1 | while ... done` with the better performing `while ... done < $1`.